# why the scroll method of a QChart object is not working

Tags: python, pyside2

why the scroll method of a QChart object is not working in pyside2 [it's working in pyqt5]
can't figure out what's the problem is , the scroll method with pyqt5 works as expected,but when you try with pyside2 it does not work

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
    series.append(1, 7)
    series.append(2, 3)
    series.append(3, 7)

    chart = QtCharts.QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.createDefaultAxes()

    chartView = QtCharts.QChartView(chart)

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()

    chart.scroll(100, 0)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

No result with pyside2

[image]

With pyqt5 everything's ok

[image]

Comment: I think it's a bug, report it

Comment: ok thank you eyllanesc, i will report it